# No-monotone sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, monotone-class-theorem

A no-monotone sequence can have limit? 
Can I consider as no-monotone sequence $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$?

Comment: Could you include definition of no-monotone sequence, so those who don't know that term don't need to look it up?

Comment: A sequence does not have to be monotonic to have a limit, as your example shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence is not monotone for if
$n$ is even then $n + 1$ is odd and $\frac{(- 1)^{n + 1}}{n + 1} < 0 <
\frac{(- 1)^n}{n}$ and if $n$ is odd then $n + 1$ is even so
that $\frac{(- 1)^n}{n} < 0 < \frac{(- 1)^{n + 1}}{n + 1}$. Further if $n$ is
even we have $\left| \frac{(- 1)^n}{n} \right| = \left| \frac{1}{n} \right| =
\frac{1}{n}$ and if $n$ is odd we have $\left| \frac{(- 1)^n}{n} \right| =
\left| \frac{- 1}{n} \right| = \left| \frac{1}{n} \right| = \frac{1}{n}$. Now
for $0 < \varepsilon$ there exists a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $0 <
\frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon$ hence if $n \geqslant N$ we have that $\left|
\frac{(- 1)^n}{n} - 0 \right| = \left| \frac{(- 1)^n}{n} \right| = \frac{1}{n}
\leqslant \frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon$ proving that $\underset{n - <
\infty}{\lim} \frac{(- 1)^n}{n} = 0$. So the answer is yes.